# How to delete 0 values but not blanks from a column in SQL Server 2008 programming?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the average of a column. I want to remove the 0 values but keep the blanks using SQL Server 2008 programming. Please help

Comment: Help us help you by providing sample data and expected result.

Comment: I'm really not sure what "keep the blanks" means in the context of computing an average. Even on the assumption that by "blanks" you mean NULLs.

Comment: And what do you mean by delete 0, do you really want to delete the whole row or just show something else instead of 0?

Comment: I think he just wants an average of everything that isn't 0, so if you have 1,2,3,0 and null you would get 1.5 (1+2+3+null)/4 rows that are not 0

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AVG()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177677.aspx)

If you wish to ignore the 0 and include "blank" (if you mean `NULL`) to the base, you can make use of the following characteristic of the function:

> AVG () computes the average of a set of values by dividing the sum of those values by the count of nonnull values.

So that

```
SELECT AVG(
    CASE WHEN [column] = 0 THEN NULL -- Skip 0 when calculate the average
         WHEN [column] IS NULL THEN 0 -- Include blank as 0 value
         ELSE [column] END) AS Average
FROM [table]
```

Comment: this is so much cleaner than what I came up with :p

Comment: You might want to add a Distinct behind your select though because right now you will get the avg result X times. X being the amount of rows in your table.

Comment: @JeremyC. Opps, just removed the `OVER ()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I guess:

```
select sum(distinct t1.val)/( count(distinct t2.id)+ count(distinct t3.id))
from mytable t1
join mytable t2
on 1=1
join mytable t3
on 1=1
where not t2.val = 0 and (t3.val is null)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7a49/2)